# flutter X firebase: how to correctly initialize fields with data in different branches in firebase realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have a piece of code trying to initialize the fields with data from two different users in the firebase realtime database, I tried various ways but all of them don't work and the field is not initialized error keeps popping up.

Here is the code:

```
class _PartnerProfilePageState extends State<PartnerProfilePage> {
  final userUID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  late final partnerUID;
  late final profilePath;
  late final partnerName;
  late final birthday;
  late final en;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initInfo();
  }

  initInfo() async {
    database.child(userUID).onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as Map);
      setState(() {
        partnerUID = data['partner'];
        en = data['language'].toString().startsWith('en');
        initPartnerInfo();
      });
    });
  }

  Future initPartnerInfo() async {
    final ppsnapshot =
        await database.child(partnerUID).child('profilePath').get();
    profilePath = ppsnapshot.value.toString();

    final nsnapshot = await database.child(partnerUID).child('username').get();
    partnerName = nsnapshot.value.toString();

    final bsnapshot = await database.child(partnerUID).child('birtday').get();
    birthday = bsnapshot.value.toString();
  }

  //rest of other unrelated stuff like build down there
}
```

(My firebase realtime database has no 'user' branch but directly save every user in the root with their userid).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the async initializing. The build method can try to build before you initialize the last variable(Because initState method can not async). You can easily check my theory.Delete the 'method call'(the initInfo) inside the initState(). Just create a button in the screen, give it a anonymous async function, inside the function call your init method and try to call your variables like this:

```
() async{
   await initInfo();
   print('partnerUID');
}
```

Easy way to checking out initialization process. Hope it helps.